# Changing Repeater class based on count in Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to be able to have different classes for repeater items based on the count. In other words, the first repeater item needs `class="single-item active"` and all other repeaters need `class="single-item not-visible move-right"`.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
      <?php if (have_rows('features')): while (have_rows('features')) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php if(!$count): ?>
        <li class="cd-single-item cd-active"></li>
        <?php else: ?>
        <li class="cd-single-item cd-not-visible cd-move-right"></li> 
      <?php $count++; endif; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a boolean to false after the first check:

```
$repeater = get_field('my_repeater_field');
$first = true;
foreach ($repeater as $sub) {
  $class = $first ? 'single-item active' : 'single-item not-visible move-right';

  // do whatever with $sub and $class here...

  $first = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct, but you're only increasing `$count` if `(!$count)` is false and this never happens because you're only increasing `$count` if… and so on.

Just put your `$count++` after the first `endif`. I rewrote it like this:

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    if ( have_rows('features') ):
        while ( have_rows('features') ) : the_row();
            if ( ! $count ): ?>
                <li class="cd-single-item cd-active"></li>
            <?php else: ?>
                <li class="cd-single-item cd-not-visible cd-move-right"></li>
            <?php
            endif;
            $count++;
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

Hope this helps!